# Capture 'self' (or class members) inside Swift @convention(block)

Tags: javascript, swift, javascriptcore

### Background/Context

JavaScriptCore allows developers to use a JavaScript library inside their Swift/ObjC application. One such method is to directly call a JavaScript function, as demonstrated in the Swift code sample below:

```swift
let firstname = "Mickey"
let lastname = "Mouse"

if let functionFullname = self.jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("getFullname") {
    // Call the function that composes the fullname.
    if let fullname = functionFullname.call(withArguments: [firstname, lastname]) { 
        print(fullname.toString() ?? "jsDemo1 name not resolved")
    }
}
```

This calls a JavaScript function, `getFullname`, as follows:

```js
function getFullname(firstname, lastname) {
    return firstname + " " + lastname;
}
```

Another option is to "assign" a function in Swift code when calling a JavaScript function, as demonstrated in the Swift code sample below:

```swift
// declare swiftJSFnImpl function (called later via JS object)
let swiftJSFnImpl: @convention(block) (String) -> Void = { value in
    print("\nJS Console:", value)
}

// assign swiftJSFnImpl to JS object
let swiftFunctionObject = unsafeBitCast(self.swiftJSFnImpl, to: AnyObject.self)
self.jsContext.setObject(swiftFunctionObject, forKeyedSubscript: "callSwiftFunctionFromJS" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol))
_ = self.jsContext.evaluateScript("callSwiftFunctionFromJS")

// call JS function with
if let fnCallSwiftFromJS = self.jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("swiftJSFnImpl") {
    // Call the function that calls a Swift function from Javascript
    _ = fnCallSwiftFromJS.call(withArguments: nil)
}
```

```js
function callSwiftFunctionFromJS() {
    var value = "hello world";
    mySwiftFunction(value);
}
```

To use a member of the class, such as `self.mySecondFunction` or `self.name` inside of an `@convention(block)` block, treat the `block` using SOLID principles, although this approach adds more complexity.

### Problem

Given a variable `jsContext: JSContext!` that is a member of the class, `BasicsViewController`, the error below occurs when attempting to access a class member inside a `@convention(block)` block:

> Cannot use instance member 'self' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

[image: error]

### Question

Is it possible to capture `self` or `context` inside of a Swift block, and if so, how?

### Workarounds

There is a workaround to capture `self` inside of a `@convention(block)` block by treating the `block` using SOLID principles, as shown in the following example:

```swift
private func getTotalPriceOfProduct(_ product: Product) -> Float? {
    let discountedPrice: @convention(block) (Float, Float) -> Float = { price, discount in
        price * (1 - discount)
    }
    jsHandler.setObject(object: discountedPrice, withName: "discountedPrice")
    
    if let value = jsHandler.callFunction(functionName: "getTotalPriceOfProduct", withData: product, type: Product.self) {
        if value.isNumber {
            return value.toNumber() as? Float
        }
        else {
            print("error while getting total price for \(product.name)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

For more information on this topic, see the following resources:

- [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/)
- [kodeco.com](https://www.kodeco.com/1227-javascriptcore-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)
- [gfrigerio.com](https://www.gfrigerio.com/swift-and-javascript-interaction/)
- (dirty workaround) [vmanot.com](https://vmanot.com/context-capturing-c-function-pointers-in-swift)